# How to switch from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I want to move from an activity to the fragment using intent. I know the opposite, but I don't know that.

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private void history() {
    Intent my = new Intent(ResultActivity.this, ThreeFragment.class);
    startActivity(my);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: You are not going from activity to fragment. Fragment lives with activity. So you should change it inside activity or open another activity with this fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Activity with fragment (Fragment is part of Activity); Add/remove fragments into your manually using FragmentManager (`fragmentManager.beginTransaction() ... .commit()`).

If you need to open new activity with fragment

```
    Intent my = new Intent(ResultActivity.this, ActivityWithThreeFragment.class);
    startActivity(my);
    finish();
```

you can define fragment class in xml layout of ActivityWithThreeFragment (using `<fragment>` tag) or add fragment manually. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This has not been resolved.